# span isn't rotating after adding a rotate class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

In the nested flip function when I call `dates[j].classList.toggle("rotateNumber")` My `console.log(dates[j])` is logging the nodes and showing that the class has been added, but when I look at the DOM tree it doesn't show the class inside the `class="number"` attribute. I've been playing with it for an hour now and can't figure it out. I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ryansaam/pen/OweQMm?editors=0010) the problem is on line 105.

```
let dates = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
        // ui module
        let rotate = 0
        document.getElementById("right-arrow").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

          rotate -= 90;
          // Reset the calendar cells
          (function filp(i) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              dateNodes[i].style.transform = "rotateY("+rotate+"deg)"
              dateNodes[i].removeChild(dateNodes[i].firstChild)
              if (i !==  41) {i++;filp(i)} else {
                rotate -= 90
                monthOffset--
                if (monthOffset === 11) { yearOffset--; console.log("true"); console.log(yearOffset)}
                fillCalendar(yearOffset,monthOffset);
                console.log(dates);

                (function filp(j) {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    dates[j].classList.toggle("rotateNumber")
                    console.log(dates[j])
                    dateNodes[j].style.transform = "rotateY("+rotate+"deg)"
                    if (j !== 41) {j++;filp(j)}
                  }, 5)
                })(0);
              }
            }, 5)
          })(0);
```